# Adding button near to back button in UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I would like to add button to my navigation Bar.

Now when i'm adding an UIViewController i'm using:

```
pushViewCntroller
```

and automaticlly back button added and i'm setting title. I can add button to right side with `serRightBarButtonItem`

but i would like to add button near to the back button, How can i do it? can I add it by customized CGpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set multiple buttons on your navigation bar like this:

```
// Get a copy of the existing array listing your current buttons
NSMutableArray *leftButtonArray = [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems mutableCopy];

// Create the UIBarButtonItem
UIBarButtonItem *newButton = <insert your code to create your button>;

// Add it to the array.  Adjust index 0 to move the button.
[leftButtonArray insertObject:newButton atIndex:0]; 

// Set the left buttons to the new array
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = leftButtonArray;
```

Comment: I tried it, but the button in array is taking the place of the standard back button, i want to added it near to this button...

Comment: As I said in the comment, adjust the index to move the button. (change `atIndex:0` to `atIndex:1` on the third line of code to move it to the right side.)